# connection closed unexpectedly (ubuntu 20.04 tigervnc server, win10 RealVnc client)

Tags: networking, server, ssh, vnc

On my arm64 computer (Ubuntu 20.04) I was using tightvnc until this morning.

I found when I resize the window it often gets stuck and disconnected.

I've seen this previously so I remembered I can use tigervnc (in the past I switched to vnc4server, but my other Ubuntu 20.04 machine is using tigervnc so I decided to change to that).

I removed tightvnc and installed tigervnc.

The .vnc/xstartup is like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
exec startxfce4
```

The log from `vncserver -localhost no :1 -geometry 3840x2160` at the server side is `connection closed unexpectedly` on the client side is like this (.vnc/n1sdp:1.log)

```
Xvnc TigerVNC 1.10.0 - built Apr  9 2020 06:49:31
Copyright (C) 1999-2019 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.rst)
See https://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.
Underlying X server release 12008000, The X.Org Foundation


Fri Oct  1 16:26:58 2021
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on all interface(s), port 5901
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
xrdb: No such file or directory
xrdb: can't open file '/home/ckim/.Xresources'
/usr/bin/startxfce4: X server already running on display :1
gpg-agent[2705]: WARNING: "--write-env-file" is an obsolete option - it has no effect
gpg-agent: a gpg-agent is already running - not starting a new one

(xfce4-session:2675): xfce4-session-WARNING **: 16:26:59.089: gpg-agent returned no PID in the variables

(xfce4-session:2675): xfce4-session-WARNING **: 16:26:59.090: xfsm_manager_load_session: Something wrong with /home/ckim/.cache/sessions/xfce4-session-n1sdp:1, Does it exist? Permissions issue?

(xfwm4:2707): xfwm4-WARNING **: 16:26:59.241: Unsupported GL renderer (llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0, 128 bits)).

** (wrapper-2.0:2740): WARNING **: 16:26:59.589: No outputs have backlight property

** (light-locker:2754): ERROR **: 16:26:59.607: Environment variable XDG_SESSION_PATH not set. Is LightDM running?
Failure: Module initialization failed

** (xiccd:2758): WARNING **: 16:26:59.678: EDID is empty

** (xiccd:2758): CRITICAL **: 16:26:59.704: failed to create colord device: failed to obtain org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-device auth

(wrapper-2.0:2741): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 16:26:59.818: g_file_new_for_path: assertion 'path != NULL' failed

(wrapper-2.0:2741): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 16:26:59.818: g_file_monitor_file: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed

(wrapper-2.0:2741): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 16:26:59.818: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(wrapper-2.0:2741): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:26:59.818: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(wrapper-2.0:2741): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:26:59.818: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkToggleButton to a container of type XfcePanelPlugin, but the widget is already inside a container of type XfcePanelPlugin, please remove the widget from its existing container first.

(wrapper-2.0:2740): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:26:59.821: Negative content width -3 (allocation 1, extents 2x2) while allocating gadget (node button, owner PowerManagerButton)

(wrapper-2.0:2741): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:26:59.843: Negative content width -3 (allocation 1, extents 2x2) while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkToggleButton)

Fri Oct  1 16:27:02 2021
 Connections: accepted: 129.254.132.39::12282
 SConnection: Client needs protocol version 3.8
 SConnection: Client requests security type VncAuth(2)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rdr::Exception'
terminate called recursively
(EE) 
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE) 0: /usr/bin/Xtigervnc (OsLookupColor+0x188) [0xaaaac18f6038]
(EE) unw_get_proc_info failed: no unwind info found [-10]
(EE) 
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Caught signal 6 (Aborted). Server aborting
(EE) 
X connection to :1.0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
Gdk-Message: 16:27:06.768: evolution-alarm-notify: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.0.

Gdk-Message: 16:27:06.768: nm-applet: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.0.

Gdk-Message: 16:27:06.768: xfce4-panel: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.

Gdk-Message: 16:27:06.768: wrapper-2.0: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.

Gdk-Message: 16:27:06.768: wrapper-2.0: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.

Gdk-Message: 16:27:06.768: xfdesktop: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.

Gdk-Message: 16:27:06.768: Thunar: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.

Gdk-Message: 16:27:06.769: wrapper-2.0: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.

Gdk-Message: 16:27:06.771: wrapper-2.0: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.

Gdk-Message: 16:27:06.772: xfsettingsd: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.

Gdk-Message: 16:27:06.774: xfwm4: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.

Gdk-Message: 16:27:06.774: xfce4-session: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.


(wrapper-2.0:2739): libnotify-WARNING **: 16:27:24.829: Failed to connect to proxy
Gdk-Message: 16:27:24.830: wrapper-2.0: Fatal IO error 9 (Bad file descriptor) on X server :1.
```

I do not know what is main problem here.

I'm not sure this is relevant but I used ssd open key from my other machine in this arm64 machine to access a git repository.

Could someone tell me what's wrong here? (I found https://www.hiroom2.com/2018/05/07/ubuntu-1804-xrdp-xfce-en/ but I'm not sure if this will fix it. I tried until step 3's echo "xfce4-session" > ~/.xsession and stopped because I want to use xfce4)